# how to create all combinations of n numbers by being able to use numbers multiple times recursively

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

as an example I have numbers 0 and 255. I want combinations that would look like this

[[0, 0], [0, 255], [255, 0], [255, 255]]

my current code looks like this, where "a" is the list of numbers, it could be 2 or more.

```
def combinations(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return [[]]
    final = []
    for i in combinations(a[1:]):
        final += [i, i+[a[0]]]
    return final
```

but it instead gives this output [[], [0], [255], [255, 0]]

I am looking for a way to solve it recursively without using any libraries.

Comment: if your list is [0, 255] then [0,0] and [255, 255] are not combinations in that list

Comment: @d_kennetz then what are they called

Comment: The function can receive a list of any size?

Comment: @EduardoTolmasquim yes, meaning combinations can get quite large in numbers.

Comment: So the sizes of the lists that are returned are to be the same as the size of the list with possible values? Or is that pure coincidence in your example?

Comment: @trincot yes exactly, if there were 3 numbers, all "combinations" would be with the length of 3

Comment: What you are looking for is called a Cartesian product - specifically, of the same list with itself multiple times. See the linked duplicate. `itertools` is in the standard library and unless you are trying to teach yourself to write recursive algorithms, you don't have a realistic reason to avoid it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel wherever i am executing this task, I cant use any libraries at all. I found solutions with that library before i came here, but i just cant use it.

Comment: Why can't you use it? If it's for homework then a) you should ask your instructor for help first; b) read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822.

Comment: Are the given numbers always distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use itertools for that:

```
from itertools import product
lst = [0, 255]
[p for p in product(lst, repeat=2)]
# [(0, 0), (0, 255), (255, 0), (255, 255)]
```

Since you do not want to import libraries, you can also look up the documentation of [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and use the function directly:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)


lst = [0, 255]
[p for p in product(lst, repeat=2)]
```